# How did "Matron" and "Patron" come to mean different things?

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences, latin

[Matron](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/matron?s=t):

(1) a married woman, especially one who is mature and staid or dignified and has an established social position;
(2) a woman who has charge of the domestic affairs of a hospital, prison, or other institution;
(3) a woman serving as a guard, warden, or attendant for women or girls, as in a prison.

[Patron](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/patron?s=t):

(1) a person who is a customer, client, or paying guest, especially a regular one, of a store, hotel, or the like;
(2) a person who supports with money, gifts, efforts, or endorsement an artist, writer, museum, cause, charity, institution, special event, or the like;
(3) a person whose support or protection is solicited or acknowledged by the dedication of a book or other work;
(4) patron saint;
(5) *Roman History.* the protector of a dependent or client, often the former master of a freedman still retaining certain rights over him;
(6) *Ecclesiastical.* a person who has the right of presenting a member of the clergy to a benefice.

They both ultimately came from Latin *mater* and *pater*, didn't they? And why does Matron have relatively similar meanings while Patron has several different ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entry for [patron](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/patron?s=t) primarily denotes *patronus* (protector) as the origin of patron, and *patronus* as a derivative of *pater* (father), which [wikitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patronus) confirms. The connection then becomes *father* -> *protector* -> *supporter* -> *paying customer*, which follows a relatively logical progression, and explains the many different definitions that the word took on throughout history, as you listed them.

*Mater*, on the other hand, apparently did not have the same connotation of being a protector, so it became *matrona*, which simply means "married woman". This led to a far less diverse evolution of its meaning, as is evidenced by the few, similar definitions for it.